# Map Guid to column in Fluent NHibernate with constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a simple entity

```
public class SiteEntity
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Guid PublicId {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I am mapping it using `Fluent NHibernate` package to achieve the following constraints:

- `Id` is internal DB identifier so it is created automatically and defined as PK
- `PublicId` is a public unique id. It is defined as a column with unique and not null constraint and is generated on insert much like PK
- `Name` is description so it is required (not null) but can be anything

As result I have the following mapping

```
public class SiteEntityMap : ClassMap<SiteEntity>
{
    public SiteEntityMap()
    {
        Table("T_SITE");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("site_id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.PublicId, "site_public_id").Generated.Insert().ReadOnly().Unique().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Name, "site_name").Not.Nullable().CustomType("AnsiString").Unique().Length(512);
        ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Now, if I create the schema using NHibernate mapping it is created as I like. However, an attempt to save `SiteEntity` which has field `Name` initialized results in `GenericADOException` with the message:

> "could not insert: [IWS.Configuration.DataModel.SiteEntity][SQL: INSERT INTO T_CFG_SITE (site_name) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]"

If I remove `Not.Nullable()` from the mapping of the `PublicId` property everything works but the field in DB allows NULLs.

Please, advise how I can map a Guid property to not nullable column with autogenerated value on insert.

Comment: Did you check how the entity is contructed just before inserting?

Comment: It seems like site_name is null, did you check it? Did you check whether there is some trigger? Take a look at this table: T_CFG_SITE

Comment: Yes, when I call `session.Save(siteEntity)` the object has value in the Name property. I wrote in the question that although the message is what it like, the actual problem is in the mapping of the `PublicId` property. Please, re-read the question and let me know what is unclear, so I can rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Fluent NHibernate lacks a way to dictate implicit generating logic for this kind of values. It is possible to define a Default value, but the use of DB specific functions breaks the DB abstraction. Unfortunately, `Generated` property does not expose any way to inject a code that generates a value for Insert() operation (or for Update()).
The short answer is "there is no way to enforce generating a value implicitly or declare the code that does it at time of the mapping".